# GWT overriding theme CSS

Tags: css, gwt, popup

I have a PopupPanel, and I want to override some of the styles from the default theme. Eclipse gave me a .css in the doc root, and I put the styles I want to override in there. Inspection from the browser at runtime shows my styles being overridden by the GWT theme.

It's hard to believe that this is the default setup for a new project - an application .css that is loaded after the stock css?

I tried loading my css in my module XML (using stylesheet tag), but that has no effect, it's not loaded at all. The GWT docs say this is deprecated, so I suspect it's just been removed. Regardless, I don't want to use a deprecated interface.

To be clear, this is an ordering problem. I've verified my css is loaded correctly by inspecting the DOM. I can see my styles applied to the element in question, and I can see them overridden by the GWT theme css (dark.css in this case). Adding the `!important` flag does get my styles applied, but that's obvsiously not the right solution.

The popup is instantiated in the click handler of an anchor that's defined in a UI widget. The popup itself isn't defined in the template, I simply instantiate it and call show(). I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Can someone describe to me how this should be accomplished? If this is any harder than "put line XXX in file YYY", I'm going to seriously lose my faith in GWT.

Answer (score 2):

GWT just generates some HTML to which CSS is applied. It looks complicated but there isn't any magic going on in the final output. Just HTML, CSS and some JS.

If your PopupPanel is picking up the wrong style it's because the browser isn't seeing your style, or the style in the standard theme (which is standard.css) is taking precedence.

If you have a DOM editor:

1. Inspect the element and see what styles it has against it.
2. Verify your style sheet is being included
3. Verify your style rules are being applied to the element as well.

Most likely it's a simple CSS error of some kind and GWT is the red herring. However if you can't see the error you can consider:

1. Give your element an id or its own additional style and use a rule to override the default behaviour.
2. Completely override .gwt-popupPanel with the style you want to apply everywhere
3. Subclass PopupPanel. Call the super
   constructor but then strip out the
   gwt-popupPanel style and replace it
   with your own style instead. Or
   augment the gwt-popupPanel and add
   an extra style of your own.
4. Copy the entire default theme and rename it as something else and use that in your project.

The best option is probably the simplest which would be 1)

Comment: to be clear, this is a problem of loading order. i've already verified that my css is getting loaded. inspecting the DOM, i can see my css applied to the element in question. i can also see my css overridden by the GWT theme css (dark.css in this case). i can get my style applied if i add the !important flag to my styles, but that's obviously not the right solution.

Comment: and yes, i'd like to do 1-2, but if it's an ordering problem, that's impossible right? if 3 is an option, could you provide a few more details? 1 or 2 would be preferable though.

Comment: If you look at the source code for PopupPanel you should see that during construction it calls "setStyleName(DEFAULT_STYLENAME);" where DEFAULT_STYLENAME is "gwt-PopupPanel". Therefore if you subclass and call the super(), before removing the style, and setting your own it won't apply to that class any more.

Comment: As for CSS order, I expect GWT honours the order in your module XML. If you expliticly define a theme, try commenting it out or ensuring your <stylesheet> decl occurs below it. In your target folder you should see a file with a name ending .nocache.js. This JS is the bootstrap for your app and is the file that injects the CSS tags from an onBodyDone() method. You can verify the order the css is included from looking at that.

Comment: 1. setting the style name directly works (don't need to subclass, just call setStyleName()), but there are other styles i need to override also, like the popup panel "glass". this approach isn't scalable across all the possible customizations i might need to make to the stock themes and i should not need to write hava code to have a style applied! 2. the stylesheet module XML tag is deprecated, and has no effect. if i understood how to define by own theme that is a peer to the standard themes, perhaps i could have that loaded in the same way?

Comment: testing shows that it *will* load two themes w/ two "inherits" module XML lines ... which then opens the topic of how to create and package a custom theme. looking at the default themes, that doesn't look trivial.

Comment: The <stylesheet> tag may be deprecated but it still works. You could of course put the css in the host html but then it's going to get overridden when the GWT app kicks off. You could also write a bootstrap in your Module impl which also injects the CSS after your app starts up. I think given the effort, it's easier to just see if <stylesheet> resolves the problem and then worry about how to do it right later which may be to write your own theme.

Comment: yes i've tried <stylesheet>, and it does not resolve the problem.